# MS Access 2010: query slows down dramatically when using parameters

Tags: performance, ms-access, parameters

I hope this was not asked here before (I did search around here, and did google for an answer, but could not find an answer)

The problem is: I'm using MS Access 2010 to select records from a linked table (There are millions of records in the table). If I specify criteria (e.g. Date) directly (for example date=#1/1/2013#), the query returns in an instant. If i use parameters (add a parameter of type date/time and provide value of 1/1/2013 when prompted (or date in some different format), or reference a control in a form), the query takes minutes to load.

Please let me know if You have any ideas on what could be causing this. I do feel bad about asking such a question and possibly wasting someones time...

Comment: Is this linked table in another .accdb file, or is it an ODBC linked table? If the latter, what is the back-end database? (SQL Server...? Oracle...?)

Comment: It is an ODBC linked table, the database is Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a potential answer, I didn't know this myself and did a little digging.

*If performance is important, it may be necessary to prefer dynamic SQL even for where parameter queries are suitable due to how queries are optimized. Generally, Access creates a plan for a new query upon saving. **When a query contains a parameter, then Access cannot know what value the parameter may contain and has to make a "good guess"**. Depending on which actual values are later supplied, it may **be okay or poor, resulting in sub-optimal performance.** In contrast, dynamic SQL sidesteps this because the "parameters" are hard-coded into the temporary string and thus a new plan is compiled with that value, guaranteeing optimal execution plan. Since compiling a new plan at runtime is very fast, it can be the case that dynamic SQL will outperform parameter queries.*

**Source**:  http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Parameter_Query#Performance

Also, if I had to **guess**, in your parameter query, Access is requesting the ENTIRE table from Oracle and **then** filtering down with your where clause, but when the WHERE clause is specified, it actually just loads those records and possibly makes use of indexes.

As far as a solution, I would build your query string in VBA then execute it. It opens you up to injection, but you can handle that. So:

Instead of using a **saved parameter query object** in Access, try to do something like this.

```
 dim qr as string
 qr = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate = #" & me.dateControl & "#;"
```

<s>'CurrentDb.execute qr, dbFailOnError</s>

```
  Docmd.RunSQL qr
```

Or, as you replied,  `currentdb.openrecordset(qr)`
This would force the engine to make an execution plan at runtime rather than having a saved potentially suboptimal plan. Let me know if this works out for you, I'd be interested to see.

Comment: +1 for the reference; I didn't know that, either. As for the "guess", if that is indeed the case then it could very well be more a function of the Oracle ODBC driver than of Access itself. I just did a quick test against SQL Server 2005 and the SQL Profiler showed some slight differences in the handling of Access queries with and without parameters (against a SQL Server linked table), but in neither case did SQL Server barf the entire table back to Access.

Comment: @GordThompson I've had a lot of experience with Oracle and a lot of experience with Access, but never with both, so my guess is really a shot in the dark with nothing to back it up.

Comment: @Scotch Your idea seems to be working, though the "CurrentDb.execute" returns an error _"Cannot execute a select query. (Error 3065)
You tried to use the Execute method with a select query. The Execute method is valid only with action queries. Select queries contain a SELECT statement and can return records; action queries do not."_  With "DoCmd.RunSQL" i got it working. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Scotch oh my.. I feel so foolish.. what I wanted to say was "
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(qr)" (rs is a recordset) but somehow in a rush I wrote "DoCmd.RunSQL". Sorry, from now on I will always check twice what i'm pasting.

Comment: You can also force the datatype for the parameter by specifying it in the query design. With the query open in design view look at the Design ribbon, on the far left you should see a button called Parameters (2007 on, it's also available in previous versions just in one of the menu's). Click this and a simple table opens where you specify the parameter and datatype. The query plan uses this info to optimize.

Comment: @PeterLake I have tried that and the query still took a while to load

Comment: Did CurrentDb.openrecordset run faster than what you were doing before?

Answer (score 0):

Of course the above reference about using parameters with Access (JET/ACE) ONLY applies to access back ends, not ODBC ones like SQL server or oracle. Since you pointed out that your using Oracle here then creating a view or using a pass-though query would and should resolve this performance issue. However one does NOT want to use Access/JET paramters with data coming from some server based system - you best just send the server SQL strings, but much better would be to use a pass-though query. If the result set requires editing, then PT query are only readonly, and you have to create a view and link to that view.